# how to redirect when a function variable missing

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
  public function index($id)
   {

    if($id == NULL){  // when  $id value missing then redirect

         return redirect('service');

    }else{
      // some operation perform  

  }
```

I want to perform some action on id value when id value missing user `redirect` to service page,value coming from get method here please help me ,this is not working

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to tell in your arguments the null value

```
public function index($id = null)
```

If no value, $id = null. So you can redirect easily.

Answer (score 2):

Add a default value `NULL` for `$id` in function definition itself.

If the function does not get any value, it will `NULL`

Check if the function is getting blank `$id` by using [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function.

This way, your functionality of redirection will work properly.

Also, your warning will get removed.

```
public function index($id = NULL) {
 if (empty($id)) {  // when  $id value missing then redirect
  return redirect('service');
 }
 else {
  // some operation perform
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your function as below:

```
public function index($id = '') {
    if(!trim($id)){  // when  $id value missing then redirect
        return redirect('service');
    }else{
    // some operation perform  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your function as below:

```
public function index($id = '') {
    if(empty($id)){
        return redirect('service');
    }else{
      // perform operation   
    }
}
```